# Issues with MongoDB in Docker Container using Flask and Making Aggregate Query

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, bigdata, gunicorn

I have a 3 TB mongodb database on an Ubuntu system (Python 3.5.2). The database consists of twitter data so all are JSON objects. I needed to make the database accessible to multiple people via ssh tunneling so my solution was a flask application that is run via gunicorn with multiple workers. Not ideal but it is deployed and restricted to vpn users while taking in concurrent requests. The multiple users do have access to the Ubuntu computer/server but in the beginning, I had issues with anyone attempting to access the database outside of the docker container. I tried changing the connection string and I never had luck due to a server timeout error. This is why I went with the flask application. In the flask application, I have the users enter in their filename that is uploaded to the linux computer and then they run the file inside flask. The frontend is just bootstrap and using an ajax call, it will let the user know that the query is complete and then their output file is written to the linux computer. The reason that I chose that route was due to a query that output an 8.8 TB file. So far, smaller queries have worked with my flask app but the aggregate operator isn't returning anything. My ajax call will error as an empty response. To me, I'm thinking it's a timeout error in the database but I haven't had luck fixing it.

Code that isn't presenting anything:

```
myclient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
mydb = myclient["db"]
mycollection = mydb["data"]

#three phases:
pipeline = [{"$match": {"file": "2020-05-06"}}, {"$group": {"_id": 0}}, {"$project": {"_id": 0, "fil
e": 1}}] 


result = mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)
pprint.pprint(list(mycollection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

This code is called via subprocess.run() in my flask app.py file.

So far, I tried leveraging asyncio with the pipeline call before doing the above formatting. I tried asyncio because of the timeout limit but didn't have luck with it.

I'm truly open to any suggestions. Even if the suggestions are to fix the connection via docker. I'm a solo dev on this project and I've been working on this project for more time than I want to admit. Any type of discussion from more experienced devs would be fantastic because maybe I'm overcomplicating the problem.

Thank you in advance!

---

Example Desired Output
Json object with less fields than:
['created_at', 'id', 'id_str', 'full_text', 'truncated',
'display_text_range', 'entities', 'source', 'in_reply_to_status_id',
'in_reply_to_status_id_str', 'in_reply_to_user_id',
'in_reply_to_user_id_str', 'in_reply_to_screen_name', 'user', 'geo',
'coordinates', 'place', 'contributors', 'is_quote_status',
'retweet_count', 'favorite_count', 'favorited', 'retweeted',
'possibly_sensitive', 'lang', 'extended_entities', 'retweeted_status']

Desired output would be similar to this:
{"created_at": "Wed Mar 01 08:35:21 +0000 2023", "id": 1630849193026932736, "id_str": "1234567", "full_text": "full tweet text"}

I would like to basically create tweets with less columns or keys.

Comment: There's potentially a lot to unpack here. But a few tactical questions about your aggregation. First, how many documents does that `$match` stage correspond to? More importantly, what is the rest of the pipeline supposed to be doing? It is nonsensical by definition. The `$group` collapses all matching documents into a single one _and_ removes all fields except for `_id: 0`. Then the `$project` afterwards tells the server to only return the field named `file`, which doesn't exist at that point. [Playground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yHPlQO2h6Mt). It needs rewriting

Comment: Hello, as said above, your pipeline will always return an array with one empty doc in it.
Could you provide an exemple of data and the expected output of your aggregation, this way we could help you better ?

On top of that, you should consider creating an index on your matching field to make your query more efficient

Comment: @user20042973 That's exactly how I feel about it. It should be one document but I can absolutely run a different query based on your recommendations. So I'm glad that you sent me that link because I'm seeing what you're saying. The goal of my query is to grab the document that matches that and then specify the fields instead of displaying or writing all the tweet fields to a file since there is way too many.

Comment: @Fourchette I saw that as well now. I added data above and an example of my desired output. Due to the multiple layers that I have going on, I'm glad that it might be something as silly as my query formatting.

Answer (score 0):

> The goal of my query is to grab the document that matches that and then specify the fields instead of displaying or writing all the tweet fields to a file since there is way too many.

You are describing [projecting fields to return from a query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/). Assuming your `$match` stage is correct, you can accomplish your goal in aggregation with the following:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "file": "2020-05-06"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      created_at: 1,
      id: 1,
      id_str: 1,
      full_text: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ppwy-6O_4ZS).

Since `$group` isn't needed here, you could also achieve your result by using the `find()` operation directly:

```
db.collection.find({
  "file": "2020-05-06"
},
{
  _id: 0,
  created_at: 1,
  id: 1,
  id_str: 1,
  full_text: 1
})
```

[Playground demonstration](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4X-Tipx9ZjN)

Comment: Thank you! I also didn't make this clear in my question. If I wanted to count the number of tweets (multiple tweets exist in the file 2020-05-06), would I have to use aggregate still? For instance: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "file": {
        "$eq": "2020-05-06"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$file",
      "num_tweets": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])